# Displaying Polymorphic Associations in a View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

There's probably a simple answer to this, but I'm lost.

I created my first Polymorphic Association today to create an activity field.

Here's the activity.rb:

```
class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :trackable, :polymorphic => true

end
```

In the database for activities, I have the columns:

```
id
name
trackable_id
trackable_type
created_at
updated_at
```

Here's the note.rb:

```
class Note < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :activities, :as => :trackable

  after_create :create_an_activity

  def create_an_activity
    self.activities.build(:name => candidate_id)
  end

end
```

In my index.html.erb view I have:

```
<% @activities.each do |activity| %>
  <p>activity.name</p>
<% end >
```

My question is:

Currently, activity.name in the view is outputting the id because I have :name => candidate_id. A note is created for a candidate. But, what I really want it to output is candidate.full_name (which is in the candidates table). However, this doesn't work because full_name is not in the notes table. It's in the candidates table. Is there any way to access that? Candidates has_many notes and a note belongs_to a candidate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

enjoyed your skill share with Vin a couple months ago!

I believe what you're looking for can be accessed by going through the parent association, by calling self -> parent -> attribute:

```
def create_an_activity
  self.activities.create(:name => self.candidate.full_name)
end
```

Also correct me if i'm wrong, but unless you are calling a save later on, it seems like self.activities.create is what you are looking for instead of .build

Comment: Thanks so much! That worked! I'd tried it with :name => candidate.full_name, but that didn't work. I forgot to include .self. Dumb of me. One thing that's odd is that .build has been working just fine rather than .create. I wonder why? (P.S. Thanks for your kind words.)

Comment: Hmm, very interesting, I'm running mongoid, maybe it works slightly different with active record, its been too long. If you figure that out i'd be interested to know.